# Highstock Navigator Mask doesn't cover content

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm trying to style the mask covering the un-selected region in the Navigator.  I have:

```
navigator.maskFill: 'rgba(233, 233, 233, 0.7)'
```

which generates a nice grey overlay indicating the content is not currently being displayed in the chart.

Unfortunately for some reason this mask doesn't completely cover the data, as seen here highlighted in red:

[image]

The mask appears 1px too short.  Can anybody explain why, or suggest how to fix/work around this?

**Edit** jsfiddle showing example: http://jsfiddle.net/s6BmC/2/

Comment: Could you reproduce your exampel as jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s6BmC/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it looks like a bug, reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2710